# How do I get my JQuery Checkboxes show values from Knockout data binding?

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox, knockout.js

I am having problems binding my JQuery Mobile Checkboxes with my Knockout binding. All my textboxes on other parts of the form are working correctly and as you can see by this image the boolean values are set to true (Value of Join Rewards and Enter Contest).

[image]

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> 

            <legend>Sign up for extras</legend>

            <label for="IsInRewards">Join Rewards</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsInRewards" id="IsInRewards" class="custom" />

            <label for="IsEnterContest">Enter Contest</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsEnterContest" id="IsEnterContest" class="custom" />

            <br />
            Value of Join Rewards (IsInRewards) : <span data-bind="text: IsInRewards"></span>
            <br />
            Value of Enter Contest (IsEnterContest) : <span data-bind="text: IsEnterContest"></span>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

I have read that there are some issues between the way Knockout and JQuery handles events so I suspect my problem is related to that but I have been unable to figure it out. What do I need to do to have the two JQuery checkbox fields show the values from the databinding?

Comment: Can you post a link to the jQuery mobile checkbox plugin you are using?

Comment: I am using jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js, which I downloaded using NuGet

Answer (score 0):

Not difficult to do.. You can create a custom binding handler for the jquery ui checkbox http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: I have about 4 hours in trying to get the Custom binding working for my checkboxes and have not been able to get it done. I am very new to HTML/JavaScript, which is part of the problem. I have even watched your video on PluralSight and still don't get it. I am looking at the sample content now to see if I can figure it out from that. Thank for the tip in the right direction though.